# Rank of dense subgroups of $(\mathbb{R}^k,+)$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a **dense** subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}^k,+)$.

> Is it true that $\mathrm{rank}(\Gamma)\geq k$ ?

Here $\mathrm{rank}$ is the [rank of an abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group) (a.k.a. torsion-free rank), i.e., $\mathrm{rank}(\Gamma)=\dim (\Gamma\otimes\mathbb{Q})$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Sanity check (it's been a while since my algebra course): is it possible that $\mathrm{rank}(\Gamma)> k$ ?
 I think $\mathbb{Q}+\sqrt{2}\mathbb{Q}$ is an example (with $k=1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the rank of $\Gamma$ can exceed $k$.

But for $\Gamma$ to be dense, it rank must be $\ge k$.
If it has rank $r<k$, then $\Gamma\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb R
=\Gamma\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q\otimes_{\Bbb R}\Bbb R\cong\Bbb R^r$
and the embedding $\Gamma\to\Bbb R^k$ induces an $\Bbb R$-linear
map $\Gamma\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^k$. As $r<k$, this
map has proper closed image, and so $\Gamma$ cannot be dense.

Comment: Thanks, that was in fact my intuition of the problem, but I wasn't being able to formalize it.